# Welcome screen and logging in

Tags: release-freya

It seems that a new X session is created when I login from the welcome screen. Whenever I log out and in from my session - my monitors go "black" - most likely from changing tty.

Comment: Do you use teamviewer over wine?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AUKha6dN

Comment: Is this information helpful?

Comment: This is a known issue with LightDM, which I believe does indeed create a new x session.